# Polymer 1.0 dom-repeat with nested elements

Tags: polymer

I have a question regarding dom-repeat. I have two different elements like:

```
<host-element>
    <item-element></item-element>
    <item-element></item-element>
</host-element>
```

each `item-element` has an array, in which items can be added at runtime. When the `item-element`
is attached is fires an event, so that the `host-element` knows about the `item-element` within its content and adds each 
`item-element` to an array of `item-element`s to a property. To access the `item-element` 
item arrays you could bind to the property of the `host-element` like:

```
<host-element items="{{itemElements}}">
    <item-element></item-element>
    <item-element></item-element>
</host-element>
```

to print the content of the `itemElements` iterate over it with `dom-repeat`

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{itemElements}}">
    <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.values}}" as="value">
            <li>[[value]]</li>
        </template>
    <ul>
</template>
```

so far everything works as expected. When the `item-element` change the `dom-repeat` 
should redraw itself, but it is not happening. The [documentation](http://polymer.github.io/polymer/) states you could uses `dom-repeat.observe` or `dom-repeat.render`
to update the `dom-repeat` element. Using `dom-repeat.render` manually works and could be 
run automatically, but is not ideal. Therefor I am trying to find a solution with `dom-repeat.observe` with no luck so far.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{itemElements}}" observe="values.splice">
    <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.values}}" as="value" observe="????">
            <li>[[value]]</li>
        </template>
    <ul>
</template>
```

I have pushed my source to github at [source](https://github.com/sandro-k/dom-repeat/blob/master/demo/dom-repeat4.html) and a [live demo](http://sandro-k.github.io/dom-repeat/demo/dom-repeat4.html)

Thanks for your help.
Sandro

Comment: From my understanding of the documentation you only need to add the observed property to the first observe attribute: observe="values.splice value.myotherproperty"

Comment: have you tried using "notifyPath" method?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a hack to get it to work. I need to alter the array holding all items. 
The function `_itemElementChanged` is called every time a `item-element` is changed.

```
_itemElementChanged: function(){
      // the check is needed if this function is run multiple times in the same tick it would erase the whole array
      if (this.items.length > 0){
        var itemsTmp = this.items;
        this.items = [];
        this.async(function () {
          this.self.items = this.items;
        }.bind({items: itemsTmp, self: this}));
      }
}
```

The check for of `this.items.length > 0` is need incase `_itemElementChanged` is called twice 
before the async function runs. In that case `this.items` would end up empty.

This is by fare not a satisfying solution, but its the only working on I found so far.. I have updated the source to include the solution.